# Dividing a column of <td> by a an input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculated-columns

I'm stumped by this current project I'm trying to solve. I'm able to print out the exact results that I want in the console, however I can't figure out how to insert those back into their respective `tds` within the table.

```
var calc    = $('.calc'),
    odds    = $('.weight');

$(document).on('keyup keydown', '.calc', function(e){
    var curVal = calc.val();

    $(document).find('.weight').each(function(){
        var oddsVal = ($(this).text() / curVal);
        console.log(oddsVal);
    });
});
```

I'm trying to divide the text in each cell of the weight column by the `input.calc` while a user is entering data into the input so that it updates live.

You can [see a Fiddle of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/LoLrotkn/), with the results printing to the console. How can I make it so each cell in the weight column updates?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What should be updating... and when? Can you be more descriptive because the jsfiddle doesn't shed any light.

Comment: i think you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LoLrotkn/1/ but because you aren't storing the original values in an array then the issue is it continually is doing the math on the new column values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the cells are getting updated before a value is in the input, which results in 'Infinity' being created 4 times.  You can even see it in your console log.

Instead, make sure there is a value in calc before executing the function.

Furthermore, if you repeatedly change the calc field, it will do a new calculation based on the newly replaced values, which does not seem like the correct behavior.  So, instead, capture the original values on page load and use those in the calculation:

```
var originalWeights = getOriginalWeights();

function getOriginalWeights() {
    var weights = [];
    $('.weight').each(function(index) {
    weights[index] = $(this).text();
  });
  return weights;
}

$(document).on('keyup keydown', '.calc', function(e){
    if (!calc.val()) return;
    var curVal = calc.val();

    $(document).find('.weight').each(function(index){
        var oddsVal = (originalWeights[index] / curVal);
        $(this).text(oddsVal);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LoLrotkn/5/)

Comment: Thanks Rob! That's exactly what I was looking to do - I appreciate your timely and thorough response.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you have to edit both HTML and JS code. You should store the original value in a `data` attribute, and then print it inside the loop using the `value` parameter of the jquery each function. Here is your fiddle edited, hope it helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/ch1qui/LoLrotkn/3/

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `keydown` event from the event delegation as the value on the input box would not be available during `keydown`. Also having `keyup` and `keydown` would trigger the events simultaneously, triggering each block twice. Also you don't need to declare the `var calc    = $('.calc'),` globally since the element would be available during the event target on the document.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.calc', function(e){
        var curVal = $(this).val(); 
    $('table td.weight').each(function(){
         var oddsVal = $(this).text() / curVal;
         alert(oddsVal);
    });
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/LoLrotkn/4/